# Cant get Firebase in Node JS app to run

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to setup firebase JS client with NodeJS. So far here is my code

```
var firebase = require('firebase/app');

require('firebase/database');

var config = {
  apiKey: "MY_SECRET_KEY_fhcWICPI",
  authDomain: "my_fir_app.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://my_fir_app.firebaseio.com",
};
var firApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.database.enableLogging(true)

// Get a reference to the database service
var database = firebase.database();
```

Then here is one of my Firebase functions to save data to the real time database.

```
/**
 * This will save the authors of stories in Firebase
 * @param  {String} id              The ID of the author
 * @param  {String} firstName       The authors first name
 * @param  {String} lastName        The authors last name
 * @param  {Timestamp} dateCreated  The unix time stamp when the author    was created
 */
 function saveStoryAuthor(id, firstName, lastName, dateCreated) {
    database.ref('mystoriesdb/authors/' + id).set({
      first_name: firstName,
      last_name: lastName,
      date_created : dateCreated
    });
 }
```

Finally, somewhere in the middle of my code am calling this function as

```
...

saveStoryAuthor('MZ8XWXNrkG', 'Dennis', 'Richie')

...
```

However, this is what I get in the logs (since I have enabled logging)

```
$ node index.js
p:0: Browser went online.
p:0: Making a connection attempt
getToken() completed. Creating connection.
c:0:0: Connection created
p:0: Failed to get token: Error: No transports available
p:0: data client disconnected
p:0: Trying to reconnect in 326.9669258513522ms
0: onDisconnectEvents
p:0: Making a connection attempt
getToken() completed. Creating connection.
c:0:1: Connection created
p:0: Failed to get token: Error: No transports available
```

I am probably doing something wrong. Could someone help.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Have you had a chance to solve this?

Comment: Yes, the answer provided below worked for me. I just accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you havent created a service account in order to add firebase to your project with node js

Check out the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Comment: [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) says that Firebase Admin should only be use if you want to have a privileged environment (e.g. a server). Node.js can be an end-user through desktop or IoT apps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
var firebase = require('firebase/app');
```

to

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** Add the following to the root of your Webpack configuration:

```
resolve: {
    mainFields: ['main']
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

The `firebase/database` package [defines different entry points](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/database/package.json#L6-L8): `main`, `browser`, and `module`. NodeJS uses `main`. Webpack is a hipster and uses `module`.

The Firebase guys made some NodeJS-specific configuration (such as setting up *WebSocket as a transport layer*) in the entry point defined by `main`. So, after bundling, that special NodeJS-specific code isn't set up, so it errors out. Telling Webpack to just use `main` like Node resolves this issue.